# Bash profile file not sourcing

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

I am trying to add a cool smiley when my previous command was success and angry smiley if the command was not success in my terminal.

```
    21:26:30 user@mymachine:~ $ cat ~/.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:$PATH"
alias python=/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3

highlightExitCode(){

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo -e '\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e ';
    else
        echo -e '\xf0\x9f\xa4\xa8 ';
    fi
}

export PS1="\[\033[1m\]\t\[\033[m\] \[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\] \$(highlightExitCode)\$ "
```

Added this code in my .bash_profile and trying to source it.
But getting this error.

```
21:30:45 user@mymachine:~ $ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 9: `    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then'
```

line number 9 is the if condition. I tried many combinations of removing the square bracket or the ';' but no luck. What am I missing here ?

I am running bash shell

```
21:30:46 user@mymachine:~ $ echo $0
-bash
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Yep, I copied and pasted from the question and it works fine.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question adding the lines before your function?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity added my entire bash_profile file in the question

Comment: The same as at 'choroba' and 'Nick Matteo' - it works at my side.

Good point from 'schrodigerscatcuriosity', problem is somewhere before...

Comment: @TinyRick I tried your whole code -it works at my side - no errors sourcing it.

Comment: Tried moving the function to the bottom of my file. Getting the same error. 
```22:03:42 cbit011102@CB/IT/01/1102:~  $ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 9: `    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then'
```
But I am now getting the smiley though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can provoke that exact error by inserting some invisible control character (other than carriage-return) at the beginning of the line containing the `if`-statement. Such a character will be visible as `^X` (for some upper-case character `X`) if you view the file with `cat -v` in the terminal.

You can probably spot the character if you edit the file with `vim` and easily remove it, or you could try simply copying and pasting the file from your question above to get rid of the character.

The character was probably inserted by accidentally hitting <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (to paste?) and then some other control sequence. Some editors, like `vim` and `vi`, and the shell too, insert the following character verbatim if you first press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, allowing you to insert raw control characters.

I haven't looked too closely at your prompt string, but you shouldn't need to export it as `PS1` is strictly used by the current shell only.  Likewise, you should not need to export `PATH` as that is already an environment variable (unless you've managed to `unset` it at some point prior).

The `PS1` value could also benefit from being single-quoted rather than double-quoted, and you have some issue with your escape sequences that make the shell lose track of the prompt's length, but I haven't tried to figure out what that might be, but it possibly has to do with the smiley itself.

Comment: I am not able to find the invisible control character using the ```cat -v ~/.bash_profile ``` command